# GIT - gitk and git bash won't open anymore on windows 7

Tags: git

I used to open a git bash right-clicking a directory (i'm on win7 64), but today it doesn't work anymore (the console pops up for a second and then disappears).

I am still able to use a git bash inside my phpstorm terminal, and if i issue a `gitk` command there, i'm getting the following error

```
m.AllocationBase 0x0, m.BaseAddress 0x68550000, m.RegionSize 0x4E0000, m.State 0x10000
E:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap (0x68550000 <0x24B0000>) in child, Win32 error
0
```

git version:

```
git version 1.7.8.msysgit.0
```

These git bash and gitk are daily tasks i perform *tons* of times a day, since years. They just broke without apparent reason.
Any help?

Comment: How is your disk space? Check that it's not full.

Comment: This post contains information that might be helpful for you as well.

http://jakob.engbloms.se/archives/1403

Comment: Things appart, your version is a lot too old (4 years!). First thing to do in this case, update. Especially because new version (>2.7) are much more reliable...

Comment: Apparently, a reboot solved this. Thanks for your pointers guys